# What is the formula of gradient boosting trees model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, xgboost, data-science-model

I have been reading about gradient boosting trees (GBT) in some machine learning books and papers, but the references seem to only describe the training algorithms of GBT, but they do not describe the formula of a GBT model. So, I am not sure how a GBT model predict a new instance.

What is the formula of a GBT model? Are there any references which describe the formula of the model?

Thanks
David